# Decode more than on ID with two tables

Tags: sql

TABLE PEDIDO

```
id_name | ID_cabimento | ID_direction

1 | 4 | 5
2 | 3 | 6
3 | 4 | 5
```

TABLE USER

```
id_name | name

1 | João
2 | Maria
3 | António
4 | Manuel
```

I WANT FOR RESULT

```
name | cabimento | direction

João | Manuel | Tozé
Maria | António | Joaquim
António | Manuel | Tozé
...
```

I tried UNION and JOIN but did not get the desired result... because I only can decode 1 ID.

Comment: what database backend are you using, the answer is database sepcific.

Comment: I think you are looking for a join but those tables don't really seem to be related in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 1):

you can join n times on same table, just using n aliases

```
select n.name as name, c.name as cabimento, d.name as direction
from pedido p
inner join user n on p.id_name = n.id_name
inner join user c on p.id_name = c.id_cabimento
inner join user d on p.id_name = d.id_direction
```